# External Single Sign On Provider with Token in the Request Header?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin, session-cookies

I work in an agency where we have been directed to use an in house single sign on solution where our application redirects to their login portal and their portal redirects back with a token and identity information in the http headers. It is then up to us to decide how to proceed.

Our application does not intend to store their identity any longer than the session allows. What is the best `DefaultAuthenticationType` to use if we just want the session to last 20 minutes or so in an MVC 5 app where a specific controller needs authentication.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
        LoginPath = new PathString("/home"),
        CookieHttpOnly = true,
        CookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "External",
        CookieDomain = ".my.com"
    });
}
```

We were thinking we might temporarily store the usable information via Entity and store the token in a session cookie, but not committed to doing exactly that. The token is definitely not guessable.

Comment: Also set `SlidingExpiration = false` to disable automatic renewals.